# nginx shows 502 bad gateway error after upgrade to LTS 22.04.1

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, nginx

I just upgraded to the latest LTS version 22.04.1. Everything went smoothly and I was asked to reboot the server to finish the upgrade. Post this, when I try to access my webserver, I see the error `502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)`.

From the error logs, I see this: `[notice] 50936#50936: using inherited sockets from "7;8;"`

Both the nginx and the mysql servers are active and running. How do I fix this?

Comment: A number of things can cause a 502 with nginx. The notice that you posted *shouldn't* result in a 502 as it's just a notice, not an error. What sort of site is being hosted? Is it a PHP-based site? Are you forwarding from nginx to a Docker container? Have you confirmed AppArmor is not getting in the way of internal communications? 

Comment: @matigo Yes, it is a Wordpress site. Simple nginx based server running mysql and php on it. Not sure what AppArmor is.

Comment: 22.04 uses PHP 8.x, which is much less forgiving of deprecated coding styles and errors than 7.x was. You’ll want to check the logs to see whether there are coding errors, most likely within a plug-in or theme, that is not being parsed and resulting in that 502 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

502 means nginx was unable to connect to upstream, which is php-fpm in your case. PHP was probably updated with distro upgrade.

```
ls /var/run/php/
php8.1-fpm.pid  php8.1-fpm.sock  php-fpm.sock
```

Note the `php8.1-fpm.sock`

In `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`, there should be something like:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

It was php7.4 before update, and now that socket does not exist, so nginx can't pass the files to php-fpm. Simply change `/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock` to the new socket filename, do `nginx -s reload`, and it should work again. Even better, change it to `/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock` which is a symlink to the actual PHP socket regardless of version (based on the default PHP installed). Then you won't have to change it each time you upgrade.

Comment: In 22.04, the new socket is aptly named `php8.1-fpm.sock` because those are version name compliant.  However, you can also point at `/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock` which is a symlink to the actual PHP socket regardless of version (based on the default PHP installed).  In case you want to actually complete your link with the full proper paths to use here for the example configuration.  And yes, PHP **was** updated with the distro upgraded, no 'probably' about it.

Comment: This worked and I've changed the new socket to point to `var/run/php/php-fpm.sock` as suggested by @ThomasWard. On the new distro, `var/run/php/php-fpm.sock` points to `/etc/alternatives/php-fpm.sock` which then points to `/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock`. Thank you for all your assistance.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to point to /var/run/php/php-fpm.sock instead of the specific version, so that my server won't break again each time I change PHP versions.